# I need write a program that should return the amount of notes and coins for the customer's change

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm writing a program that should returns the customer change and the amount of notes and coins for the customer's change.

It's working well when the bill amount is bigger than the cash (it's showing the error message about how much is missing). But its not accepting when it's a decimal number (e.g: 10.25).

It's parcial working when the cash amount is bigger than bill amount (it's showing how many of each notes is needed but when its a decimal it's not recognizing either. Also is not showing how much is the change).

And on the other cases:

- When the cash amount and bill amount are equal "Exact amount. No change." message it's not being showed.

```js
/* Declaring all the variables required */
const totalPrice = document.querySelector("#bill-amount")
const totalPaid = document.querySelector("#cash-amount")
const invalidInput = document.querySelector(".invalid-input")
const noteTds = document.querySelectorAll("#note-values td")
const billForm = document.querySelector("#bill-form")
/* Add event listeners */
billForm.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmission)

/*Add functions */
function handleFormSubmission(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  validateCashAndFillTable(totalPrice.value, totalPaid.value)
}

function validateCashAndFillTable(totalPrice, totalPaid) {
  const {message, result} = validateAmounts(totalPrice, totalPaid)
  if (!result) {
    printError(message);
    return;
  }
  const change = (totalPaid - totalPrice)
  const notes = [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]

    if (change > 0) fillTableWithNotes (notes, change) 
    return {
      message: `Customer change is ${result}`
    }
}

function fillTableWithNotes (notes, change) {
  for (let index =0; index < notes.length; index++) {
    const notesNumber = parseInt(change / notes[index])
    change = change % notes [index]
    noteTds[index].innerText = notesNumber;
    if (change === 0) 
    return{
      message: `Exact amount. No change.`
    }
  }
}

function printError(message) {
  invalidInput.innerText = message
  invalidInput.classList.add("active")
}

function validateAmounts (totalPrice, totalPaid)  {
  if(!isNaN(totalPaid) && !isNaN(totalPrice)) {
    if (parseInt(totalPrice, 10) > parseInt(totalPaid, 10)){
      return{
        message: `Insufficient founds, please add ${totalPrice - totalPaid}€`,
        result : false,
      }
    }
    return {
      message: "",
      result: true,
    };
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main>
            <section class="content">
                <h1> Cash Register </h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, aliquam.
                </p>
            </section>
            <form id="bill-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" id="label-form">Bill Amount</label>
                    <label for="" id="euro">€</label>
                    <input
                    type="number"
                    name="bill_amount"
                    id="bill-amount"
                    placeholder="0.0"
                    pattern="[0-9]+"
                    required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" id="label-form">Cash Amount</label>
                    <label for="" id="euro">€</label>
                    <input
                    type="number"
                    name="cash_amount"
                    id="cash-amount"
                    placeholder="0.0"
                    pattern="[0-9]+"
                    required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <p class="invalid-input">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, laudantium!
            </p>
            <section class="output">
                <h2>Customer Change:</h2>
                <p class="result"></p>
                <table class="notes">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="note-values">
                            <th>Quantity of Notes</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                            <td>50€</td>
                            <td>20€</td>
                            <td>10€</td>
                            <td>5€</td>
                            <td>2€</td>
                            <td>1€</td>
                            <td>0.50€</td>                            
                            <td>0.25€</td>
                            <td>0.20€</td>
                            <td>0.10€</td>
                            <td>0.05€</td>
                            <td>0.02€</td>
                            <td>0.01€</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The input fields don't allow decimals.

Comment: Thank you, which input can I switch to?

Comment: your patttern doesnt allow decimals, you gotta add a period or comma to it (not sure your prefered entry, but something a long the line of `<input type="number" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$" />`

Comment: @Dorvalla Input fields with type `number` don't have a pattern. This attribute is ignored.

Comment: You can change the step to `0.01`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step

Comment: @ThomasSablik thanks for the correction, in this case it can be swapped out then to text, only not sure if it will be treated then as a string or an int in javascript

Comment: @Dorvalla Or keep the number type and add a step to allow decimals.

Comment: I change to <input type="number" step="0.01"> and worked. Now it's being accept but it's not showing how many coins on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow your inputs to accept decimals using `step="0.01"`.

You also need to round your `change` value in a few places.

You need to fix your `return` statement in the `fillTableWithNotes` function.

You need to use `printMessage` on the returned change value (I changed printError to printMessage).

```js
/* Declaring all the variables required */
const totalPrice = document.querySelector("#bill-amount")
const totalPaid = document.querySelector("#cash-amount")
const invalidInput = document.querySelector(".invalid-input")
const noteTds = document.querySelectorAll("#note-values td")
const billForm = document.querySelector("#bill-form")
/* Add event listeners */
billForm.addEventListener("submit", handleFormSubmission)

/*Add functions */
function handleFormSubmission(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  validateCashAndFillTable(totalPrice.value, totalPaid.value)
}

function roundToSecondDecimal(value) {
  if (typeof value === "string") value = parseFloat(value)
  return Math.round(value*100)/100
}

function validateCashAndFillTable(totalPrice, totalPaid) {
  const {message, result} = validateAmounts(totalPrice, totalPaid)
  if (!result) {
    printMessage(message);
    return;
  }
  const change = roundToSecondDecimal(totalPaid - totalPrice)
  const notes = [50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.20, 0.10, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]

    printMessage (fillTableWithNotes (notes, change).message)
}

function fillTableWithNotes (notes, change) {
  let originalChange = change
  for (let index =0; index < notes.length; index++) {
    const notesNumber = parseInt(change / notes[index])
    change = change % notes [index]
    noteTds[index].innerText = notesNumber;
  }
  if (originalChange === 0) 
  return{
    message: `Exact amount. No change.`
  }
  else
  return {
    message: `Customer change is ${roundToSecondDecimal(originalChange)}`
  }
}

function printMessage(message) {
  invalidInput.innerText = message
  invalidInput.classList.add("active")
}

function validateAmounts (totalPrice, totalPaid)  {
  if(!isNaN(totalPaid) && !isNaN(totalPrice)) {
    if (parseInt(totalPrice, 10) > parseInt(totalPaid, 10)){
      return{
        message: `Insufficient founds, please add ${totalPrice - totalPaid}€`,
        result : false,
      }
    }
    return {
      message: "",
      result: true,
    };
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main>
            <section class="content">
                <h1> Cash Register </h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis, aliquam.
                </p>
            </section>
            <form id="bill-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" id="label-form">Bill Amount</label>
                    <label for="" id="euro">€</label>
                    <input
                    type="number"
                    name="bill_amount"
                    id="bill-amount"
                    placeholder="0.0"
                    step="0.01"
                    required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="" id="label-form">Cash Amount</label>
                    <label for="" id="euro">€</label>
                    <input
                    type="number"
                    name="cash_amount"
                    id="cash-amount"
                    placeholder="0.0"
                    step="0.01"
                    required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <p class="invalid-input">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, laudantium!
            </p>
            <section class="output">
                <h2>Customer Change:</h2>
                <p class="result"></p>
                <table class="notes">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="note-values">
                            <th>Quantity of Notes</th>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                            <td>0</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Notes</th>
                            <td>50€</td>
                            <td>20€</td>
                            <td>10€</td>
                            <td>5€</td>
                            <td>2€</td>
                            <td>1€</td>
                            <td>0.50€</td>                            
                            <td>0.25€</td>
                            <td>0.20€</td>
                            <td>0.10€</td>
                            <td>0.05€</td>
                            <td>0.02€</td>
                            <td>0.01€</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: You don't need to modify the pattern. It's ignored. An input field with type `number` doesn't have a pattern attribute.

Comment: Good to know! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!! I'm on a web dev course and this is m first project. Thank you all!